# Capturing laptop lid closing event in windows with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I found some good C# script in the help question "Capturing laptop lid closing event in windows?" (a previous Stack Overflow posted question). Unfortunately I am having trouble converting it to Powershell. My Powershell weaknesses preliminary reside in using Microsoft .NET Framework classes in a Windows PowerShell session, in conjunction with the Add-Type Cmdlet. This is because I do not have any formal script help resources in this area. The Stack Overflow script I was trying to convert to Powershell is listed below.

regards,

Mark

```cpp
int ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    serviceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExA(serviceName, (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX) ServiceControlHandler, 0);
    //...
    lidcloseRegHandle = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(serviceStatusHandle, &GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
    //...
}

/**
* Event handler for windows service.
*/
void WINAPI ServiceControlHandler(DWORD controlCode, DWORD evtype, PVOID evdata, PVOID Context)
{
    switch (controlCode)
    {
         //...
         case SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT:
         WriteToLog("Service Control: SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT builds and fwd the msg");
         msg.control = SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT;
         msg.event_type = (int) evtype;
         msg.event_data = evdata;
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example of calling the Windows API / related C# code via PowerShell: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/1593bbb860c2d2af436a1c9414e8adfa/

Comment: That is not C# code and it's not Microsoft .Net Framework classes ...

Comment: All scripts such as this are C based scripts. Please close this Q&A for me. Thanks. - Mark